# Dell PowerConnect 2848 MCLI Mode

Tags: switch, management, dell

I have the switch put in production already Dell Power Connect 2848. Now im trying to put some ip address and configurations. The problem is that when i connect it through the serial i have just the following prompt ">". Can i configure the SNMPv3 via MCLI or should i press the config/Managed mode button. Also becouse this is production switch, what will happen if i activeate the Managed mode ? Do i have to reboot the switch or the switch will reboot itself ?

Also is there a way to configure SNMPv3 via MCLI

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell PC 28XX series don't support SNMPv3. If you are happy with v1 or v2, you can configure it via CLI (console) or via HTTP web (IP address).

I suggest you CLI mode, it's really straight-forward. Just use config command "snmp-server community whatever"

Source http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/powerconnect-2848_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf

As page 42 stated, the switch reboots itself when transitioning from unamanaged to managed.

Comment: Hi KorXo, the problem is that the switch in Unmanaged, just "debug", "mcli" and "help" as a command. In order to be Managed i need to press a button with a pen. But im not sure if that will reboot the Switch automatically or do i need to reboot manually in order for changes to take affect. This is Production Switch and i don't want to play with it.

Comment: Remember you have an ally, it's called manual ;). Page 42 has a detailed flow chart about transitioning modes. Yes, it reboots itself.

Comment: KorXo, ye i see this now ... its a f**** situation for me :) ... thanks !